# Cookie from My normal Window doesn't work in incognito window or any other window

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I know that websites store cookies to validate users on different websites of the same domain , but when I tried to replicate it on my gmail account it didn't work.

I am using [editthiscookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) to export and then import cookies in the incognito browser .

Theoretically the browser should log me into my gmail account but it doesn't happen.

I had read it somewhere that the servers on the backend check the ip , but that shouldn't be the problem as it's my own PC both the time.

So what's wrong going on ??

**Note:**

**1. EditThisCookie shows all the cookies including 'HttpOnly' and 'Secure'**

**2. I haven't logged off from my account on the other browser session i.e. the normal session (in case anyone might think of cookie expiration ).**

Comment: Well thats a relief

Answer (score -1):

Incognito mode operates as a clean slate, it does not have access to cookies from normal mode.

Comment: But I have imported those cookies using the extension editthiscookie
So why isn't chrome signing me in

Comment: When you use incognito mode, Chrome creates a 'temporary' cookie list which is destroyed when the window/tab is closed, it does not access the 'normal' cookie list. The Chrome extension will work on the 'normal' cookie list.

Comment: I am aware of that but the point is I have a logged in session in the main browser and those cookies I copied and pasted in my incognito session , I even tried a **different browser** to  check that